# Notion of Derivative in Discrete Space

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra

We are accustomed with the notion of Calculus in $\mathbb{R}$. Can we define the notion of derivative/non-derivative in $\mathbb{N}$.

I was thinking something as follows:

Let $f$ be a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself. The function $f$ is non-differentiable at a point k  if and only if $f(k-1)\neq f(k)\neq f(k+1)$.

What do you people think?

Does the notion of non-differentiability make sense?

Comment: How would you define the derivative?

Comment: There is an extensive body of literature about *difference operators*, which are discrete analogs of derivatives.  Many of the results of calculus carry over to the discrete world.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

Comment: My question is whether the notion I have defined of non differentiability make sense or not? Please clarify. It is almost same as difference operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mathematics of finite differences, sometimes called the calculus of finite differences:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

As you can see, it has a number of notable analogues to the (more familiar) calculus of a real variable.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of derivative has its use, and not so rarely in the discrete space. See, for instance rendering techniques in image processing.

Comment: But what about differentiability, which the OP asks in particular?

Comment: @L__ goes by the uniform distances in the discrete space. still depends on the context. difference of differences is a useful concept. used many.